There are multiple ReferenceQueue in the jvm, the weak reference will enqueue which referenceQueue？
1、The main thread constructs the WeakReference and puts it in the map
2、The daemon thread monitor the WeakReference that is about to be GC
3、
When I use weakHashMap, I find that the reclaimed object does not enqueue the queue in the WeakReference constructor。
I think ReferenceQueue also exists in weakhashMap,  object should be expunge during the put() function.
Question：
Can multiple ReferenceQueue exist in the jvm？ the weak reference  will enqueue which referenceQueue？
import java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;


public class ReferenceQueueTest {
   
    private static ReferenceQueue<Byte[]> rq = new ReferenceQueue<>();

    private static int _1M = 1024 * 1024;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object value = new Object();
        Map<Object, Object> hashMap =new HashMap<>();
        //Map<Object, Object> weakHashMap =new WeakHashMap<>();


        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                int cnt = 1;
                WeakReference<Byte[]> k;
                while ((k = (WeakReference) rq.remove()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(cnt++ + "回收了:" + k);
                }
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
            }
        });
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[_1M];
            WeakReference<Byte[]> weakReference = new WeakReference<>(bytes, rq);
            hashMap.put(weakReference,value);
        }

        System.out.println("HashMap.size ->" + hashMap.size());

    }
}

————————————————
Console Output：
…………
55回收了:java.lang.ref.WeakReference@3834d63f
56回收了:java.lang.ref.WeakReference@3ab39c39
57回收了:java.lang.ref.WeakReference@7cdbc5d3
HashMap.size ->100
——————————————
import java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;


public class ReferenceQueueTest2 {
   
    private static ReferenceQueue<Byte[]> rq = new ReferenceQueue<>();

    private static int _1M = 1024 * 1024;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object value = new Object();
        //Map<Object, Object> hashMap =new HashMap<>();
        Map<Object, Object> weakHashMap =new WeakHashMap<>();


        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                int cnt = 1;
                WeakReference<Byte[]> k;
                while ((k = (WeakReference) rq.remove()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(cnt++ + "回收了:" + k);
                }
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
            }
        });
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[_1M];
            WeakReference<Byte[]> weakReference = new WeakReference<>(bytes, rq);
            //hashMap.put(weakReference,value);
            weakHashMap.put(weakReference,value);
        }
        System.out.println("weakHashMap.size ->" + weakHashMap.size());
    }
}

————————————————
Console Output：
weakHashMap.size ->40
——————————————

There is no guaranty that the garbage collector runs during the loop nor that it reclaims a particular object. The results of the first program are pure luck. The outcome of the second comes at no surprise. The resulting size of the map is, like in the first program, a result of chance but it’s clear that the references are never enqueued when you don’t have a strong reference to them.

thank you for your reply, the link you provided solved my problem——The relationship between a registered reference object and its queue is one-sided. That is, a queue does not keep track of the references that are registered with it.

one more question ： When will the ReferenceQueue be GC, if the object reference  always in the queue  {The poll() or remove() methods are not executed}

Since the ReferenceQueue is referenced by a static variable, it will never get garbage collected.
